# Is there a way to configure different highlight color for specific inspection in IntelliJ-idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

In this code sample, `return` would be underlined by red in IDEA, because function return type is String, but Boolean is returned. Can I somehow change the color to orange for example but leave all other errors in red?

```
fun y(x: Any): String {
    return false
}
```

Comment: Settings->Editor->Colors and Fonts->General then scroll down to Error in the list.

Comment: @Kootli Thank you for answer. I cannot see the setting you described in IDEA 2019.3. I Assume you might mean `Settings->Editor->Color Scheme->General->Errors and Warnings->Error` - but that is setting for every error. I would like to be able to distinguish different errors with different colors.